# Laravel routes matching everything after prefix

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm trying to match a path in a URL something like the following

**My HTTP Request**

```
http://localhost/myprefix/extra/x/x/x/x/x/2/3/2/
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::group(
    ['prefix' => 'myprefix'],
    function () {
        Route::get('extra/{path}', ['as' => 'myprefix.one', 'uses' => 'MyController@index']);
        Route::get('extraOTher/{path}', ['as' => 'myprefix.two', 'uses' => 'MyController@indexOther']);
    }
);
```

**MyController.php**

```
public function index($path)
{
    // $path should be extra/x/x/x/x/x/2/3/2/
}
```

This keeps giving me error

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:
```

How can I get this working? I read somewhere about :any and :all but I could not get these working either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little bit hacky.

### Routes.php:

```
Route::group(
    ['prefix' => 'myprefix'],
    function () {
        Route::get('extra/{path}', ['as' => 'myprefix.one', 'uses' => 'MyController@index']);
        Route::get('extraOTher/{path}', ['as' => 'myprefix.two', 'uses' => 'MyController@indexOther']);
    }
);
```

Add a pattern.

```
Route::pattern('path', '[a-zA-Z0-9-/]+');
```

Now it will catch all the routes.

### Controller.php:

```
public function index($path)
{
    echo $path; // outputs x/x/x/2/3/4/ whatever there is. 

    // To get the prefix with all the segements,

    echo substr(parse_url(\Request::url())['path'],1);
}
```

Not elegant. but it should do the trick.

Comment: HI itachi, i can't get it working still, are you sure this works>

Comment: Ah nevermind it works! It's because I had a . in my path thanks alot!

Comment: Worked for me as well